# Is FILTER_SANITIZE_URL useless?

Tags: php, input, sanitization, filter-var

The documentation says:

> Remove all characters except letters, digits and $-_.+!*'(),{}|\^~[]`<>#%";/?:@&=.

What's the point of using it if it allows quotes and stuff? I can just close the `href` attribute with " then put some JavaScript. Heck, I can put JavaScript even inside the URL.

Comment: If you don't someone to close your attribute, you should be calling `htmlspecialchars`. You are using the wrong tool for the job; it's not the tool's fault.

Comment: ok so basically it's useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sure that the URL is valid. Protecting your presentation layer is up to **you** through use of well-known, battle-tested sanitization routines.